# How to get value of a tensor from a Tensorflow Mode

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using the following implementation of the `Seq2Seq` model. Now, if I want to pass some inputs and get the corresponding values of encoder's hidden state (self.encoder_last_state), how can I do it?

https://github.com/JayParks/tf-seq2seq/blob/master/seq2seq_model.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first assemble `input_feed`, similar to the predict routine. Once you have that, just execute sess.run over the required hidden layer.

To assmeble the input_feed:

```
input_feed = self.check_feeds(encoder_inputs, encoder_inputs_length, decoder_inputs=None, decoder_inputs_length=None, decode=True)
input_feed[self.keep_prob_placeholder.name] = 1.0
```

sess.run over `self.encoder_last_state`:

```
encoder_last_state_activations = sess.run(self.encoder_last_state, input_feed)
```

Comment: I have already trained the seq2seq model. I just want to get the value of the hidden layer. So, I do sess.run again, does not it again backprop??

Comment: No, in your example, in order to perform training you have to run `self.updates` which is the training operator. invoking session run on self.encoder_last_state will just compute these values.